# Please may I know why I am getting this Sshd log

Tags: ssh, brute-force

why I am getting this sshd log

```
Feb 1 13:07:57 sshd[6453]: Failed password for root from 193.34.22.63 port 28980
ssh2
Feb 1 13:08:26 sshd[6897]: Failed password for root from 91.205.189.15 port 48155
ssh2
Feb 1 13:09:57 sshd[6455]: Failed password for root from 93.34.22.163 port 28980
ssh2
Feb 1 13:10:26 sshd[6297]: Failed password for root from 89.205.165.15 port 48155
ssh2
```

Comment: Short answer? Because you are connected to the internet. Every device in the world gets stuff like this.

Comment: Consider installing fail2ban.

Answer (score 2):

With high probability someone try to login as root enumerating different password (from generator or list).

You should decide do you have business need to open `ssh` to internet. And if yes to take actions to avoid possibility of login. This can be done by using only ssh key to login as `root` and disable password for this user